# String.ToUpper does not capitalize string when passing to DevExpress TextEdit control

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

Can someone explain me why first code block doesn't work while second one does. In first example string is not capizalized when control lose focus.

Don't work (not capitalized):

```
private void nameTextEdit_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Properties.Settings.Default.capitalizeCustomer != false)
    {
        string userEnteredString = nameTextEdit.EditValue.ToString();
        string capitalizedString = userEnteredString.ToUpper();
        nameTextEdit.EditValue = capitalizedString;
    }
}
```

Work's OK (when control lost focus text is capitalized):

```
private void nameTextEdit_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Properties.Settings.Default.capitalizeCustomer != false)
    {
        string userEnteredString = nameTextEdit.EditValue.ToString();
        nameTextEdit.EditValue = userEnteredString.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "doesn't work"?

Comment: Who knows. Attach a debugger. Put your mouse over the variables.

Comment: They sure look like they should behave exactly the same. Are you sure it doesn't have something to do with the `capitalizeCustomer` setting?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that introducing an intermediate variable `capitalizedString` will cause that issue. What is the value of `capitalizedString` just before you assign it to `nameTextEdit.EditValue`, what type is the latter, what does its documentation say about its setter?

Comment: I didn't realize that this was bad question to get down votes in seconds. I'm really trying to understand why first example does not capitalize string.

Comment: Are you sure the event fires in both examples?

Comment: Sorry. Edited my comment. First one don't work

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but what kind of control is `nameTextEdit`, what is this property `EditValue`?

Comment: DevExpress.XtraEditors TextEdit. TextEdit represents a single-line text editor just like TextBox control.

Comment: @Rik yes. Event is fired in both examples.

Comment: There is a reason to use this property instead of the correct typed Text property? EditValue is an object type.

Comment: @Steve string is capitalized when i add .ToUpper. But when passing that to control string is automatically displayed as lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange, both examples should have the same effect.

My best guess is you accidentally did

```
nameTextEdit.EditValue = userEnteredString;
```

Instead of:

```
nameTextEdit.EditValue = capitalizedString;
```

Comment: No, I didn't but meanwhile i found this. http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2150 . To much code for simple ToUpper

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply set `CharacterCasing` property to `Upper` and prevent lower case from the start?